# Engine flush a good Idea?

Tags: engine, dodge, viper

I overfilled my engine of my Dodge Viper by accident. After it started running really bad I put it away. Now It won't turn over. Should I flush the aerated oil out of the engine  with engine flush before changing the oil?

Comment: How much did you overfill your engine by? because I don't think an overfilled engine will not start no matter what

Comment: I have the experience of an overfilled engine not wanting to start, maybe it was also a combination of that with weak crank, but it couldn't because the oil level was "against" it. My overfill that time was almost 1/2 of full capacity (forgot what I was doing while chatting a friend). I just flushed out the excess when I realized it.

Comment: Overfilled with what? Running really bad how exactly? Put it away for how long? If you let the car sit for months, it's probably something stupid like the battery. If you let it sit for years modern ethanol-containing gas will also go bad but it should still turn over, just not run well.

Comment: "*Won't turn over*" typically means you turn the key but the engine does not rotate. Is that what is happening? Or do you mean it "*won't start*"?

Comment: Assuming that thing takes somewhere around 2 GALLONS of oil, how did you even have enough oil sitting around to overfill it by half?

Answer (score 1):

Running the engine in the current condition is only going to cause more oil issues. You need to remove some oil before running it again. You can do this by using suction to draw it out thru a hose down the dipstick tube or drain some from the pan.

Personally, if the foaming is bad, I would:

1. drain the pan
2. fill it with cheap oil and engine flush
3. run it and drain again
4. fill with clean oil

Depending how much you over filled it, it can cause issues if oil residue gets on sensors. That may be a possible explanation why it ran bad and won't start.